# Not sure what is wrong with the function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, parseint

I am completely new to this and am trying to write a program which will take inputs on a webpage and score the results in an output box. I am not sure what the problem is with this set of javascript, though I am sure that I am missing an integral piece! Any help is much appreciated!

```
function laten() { 

var Q2 = document.getElementById('twoScore').value;

if (Q2 == "") {
    Q2 = 0;}

var Q2new = 0;

if (parseInt(Q2) >= 0) && (parseInt(Q2) <= 15) {
    Q2new = 0;
} else if (parseInt(Q2) > 15) && (parseInt(Q2) <=30) {
    Q2new = 1;
} else if (parseInt(Q2) > 30) && (parseInt(Q2) <=60) {
    Q2new = 2;
} else if (parseInt(Q2) > 60) {
    Q2new = 3;
}

document.getElementById('latency').value = Q2new;

var Q5a = document.getElementById('fiveaScore').value;

if (Q5a == "") {
    Q5a = 0;}

var latenAdd = parseInt(Q5a) + parseInt(Q2new);

if (latenAdd == "") {
    latenAdd = 0;}

var latenScore = 0;

if (latenScore == "") {
    latenScore = 0;}


if (latenAdd == 0) {
        latenScore = 0;
    } else if ((latenAdd >= 1) && (latenAdd <= 2)) {
        latenScore = 1;
    } else if ((latenAdd >= 3) && (latenAdd <= 4)) {
        latenScore = 2;
    } else if ((latenAdd >= 1) && (latenAdd <= 2)) {
        latenScore = 3;
    }


if (!isNaN(latenScore)) {
        document.getElementById('latency').value = latenScore;
}
```

Comment: did you receive any error?

Comment: can we also see the html piece too?

Comment: What "problem" are you referring to?  What does this do compared to what you expect?

Comment: you should try to rewrite your statements, could be simplier to understand.

Comment: @sksallaj why needed ?. also the latest else if statement seem copy past mistake

Comment: Are you missing a final '}' (?)

Comment: html is needed to see if he is binding to the javascript properly.. it might not even be a java script problem. Also.. if I wanted to make a proof of concept, I would like to see what he's doing, and perhaps reuse the code to make a jsfiddle out of it.

Comment: @sksallaj was saying about the comment you delete.

Comment: ah.. yeh.. i caught that as soon as I posted it.. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax errors:

1. You are missing global parens in some `if` statements with multiple conditions, it should be like this:

   `if ( (condition 1) && (condition2))`
2. You are also missing a final `}`:

Here is the final fixed code:

```
function laten() { 
    var Q2 = document.getElementById('twoScore').value;

    if (Q2 == "") {
        Q2 = 0;
    }
    var Q2new = 0;
    if ((parseInt(Q2) >= 0) && (parseInt(Q2) <= 15)) {
        Q2new = 0;
    } else if ((parseInt(Q2) > 15) && (parseInt(Q2) <=30)) {
        Q2new = 1;
    } else if ((parseInt(Q2) > 30) && (parseInt(Q2) <=60)) {
        Q2new = 2;
    } else if (parseInt(Q2) > 60) {
        Q2new = 3;
    }

    document.getElementById('latency').value = Q2new;

    var Q5a = document.getElementById('fiveaScore').value;

    if (Q5a == "") {
        Q5a = 0;
    }

    var latenAdd = parseInt(Q5a) + parseInt(Q2new);

    if (latenAdd == "") {
        latenAdd = 0;
    }

    var latenScore = 0;

    if (latenScore == "") {
        latenScore = 0;
    }

    if (latenAdd == 0) {
        latenScore = 0;
    } 
    else if ((latenAdd >= 1) && (latenAdd <= 2)) {
        latenScore = 1;
    } 
    else if ((latenAdd >= 3) && (latenAdd <= 4)) {
        latenScore = 2;
    } 
    else if ((latenAdd >= 1) && (latenAdd <= 2)) {
        latenScore = 3;
    }

    if (!isNaN(latenScore)) {
        document.getElementById('latency').value = latenScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I really appreciate you taking the time to correct this!